# Why is my variable undefined in the constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular, I needed to make another variable to control the collapsible rows via ng-bootstrap, but I've made an error and I really don't know what's the problem. Probably the context of `this` is the key to the answer. I don't know.

So, here's the relevant part of my code (the `this.rowsControls` array is undefined):

```
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
  tasks: Task[];
  title: string;
  rowsControls: boolean[];

  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) {
    this.tasksService.getTasks().subscribe(x => { 
      this.tasks = x;
      x.forEach(this.rowsControls.push(true)); 
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `push` inside `undefined`, just declare an empty array (or not empty, depends on your needs, but `rowsControls` should be an array):

```
rowsControls: boolean[] = [];
```